# How to provide password when run git clone command with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, git-clone

I am making a batch file that automatically clones a git repository. 
I put the following line to the batch file

```
git clone ssh://user@address/path
```

But its execution hits me:

```
[exec] Permission denied, please try again.
[exec] Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
[exec] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Because it requires to enter the password.
I tried changing the command to

```
git clone ssh://user:password@address/path
```

But it stills asking me for the password

Any suggestion?

Comment: It is not, please read the question next time in order to corroborate. The solution provided in that post, is annuounced as an attemp in this post.

Comment: that's why votes are for. Sorry, I saw some ssh stuff in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sshpass` tool to provide passwords to the `git`:

```
sshpass -p password git clone ssh://user@address/path
```

But note that it is not security-wise and using keys is much better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to establish a public key so you don't need a password at all. It also happens to be more secure. For example create a new ssh key pair:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/git_key -C "steve@example.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/sowens/.ssh/git_key.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/sowens/.ssh/git_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:BxqMCuLKKa47IEzmAk7yRpv7MHuIwn9YWp5zlMs0O9A steve@example.com
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|     o           |
|o   . o .        |
|==..   o .       |
|X+.o  o S .      |
|*+*  + E .       |
|B=oo* * +        |
|*.o*.= *         |
|=+o+o o .        |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Then add the new git_key.pub file to your github account:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

The file will be a text file that looks like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDjk8Ae7kGBhBM/hAhxe4BpjU1HIymRel6TWGJ3E17lki9qJroNjXpqxtsd27C2QSgdEvYEbX6Qv1jeTejpDqTnPdWvjnOWnk5zAo7IhKdKqzCMkBblmHR4LoJs/CeTuNG2vyTx7hb93nBPjni2EV05jW/vkoMoZbMV/4lO1A4oX5L52h5/hGDahfOLxjoU3wfkEssQkDo83GHzk5A5O6kSb6Lv9TFdaWCMqI0ZXOj3CuH3CSCIpoqS1Kibceu3kLHLN8KQZEXQmMrBEkJ69RfugfNtTddOO3gjhVmCAAUzZsRuxGQMDgmT0tnpQaJ0DdSxFwpEFSceR0/06Zykq+dl steve@example.com
```

Comment: It is not the github repository, it is a private repository that i do not have complete access.

Comment: It would make sense to reach out to the admin of the repo.  Does the private repository expose a github user interface or is it entirely command line?